# in fixed width layout should i define width to element inside wrapper again like for header, footer, banner etc?

Tags: css, xhtml

In fixed width layout if width of layout is already defined in `#wrapper {width:970px}` then

what should i add to inner div which i want to expand fully .like for header, footer, banner etc

1. same `width:970px` to all div also
2. No need to define any width
3. or `width:100%` should be added

Comment: belongs on http://doctype.com

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez - why it's belongs on doctype.com?

Comment: should i ask same question in doctype and remove from here, or it's good to ask on both places.

Comment: I think its fine to ask it here (there are almost 10k questions tagged with `css`), but you'll probably find better answers in a design specific site.

Answer (score 1):

Either 2 or 3..

Hardcoding the same value more than once (case 1) will only lead to trouble and more work whenever you decide to change the size of the wrapper..

And from 2 and 3, better use 2 ( as @Pablo mentioned)

1. because it is greedy and will expand to its parent width.
2. because you can add additional properties like border/padding/etc that affect its size, without having to make manual adjustments..

Comment: but what is the difference in 2 and 3. Aren't both same? is 100% will behave different than no width defined

Comment: Yes.. If you define width 100% then it will be calculated to 970px. So adding padding to that will exceed this size and push or overflow the wrapper.. on the other hand if you leave it undefined it will take into consideration the padding/borders/etc before expanding to 100%

Comment: pls can u explain this by example?

Comment: @Jitendra, have a look at this page i just made that show these cases.. http://jsbin.com/ikera3/3 (IE will expand the wrapper to fit contents but it is a bug..)

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is number **2**.

`divs` by default take as much horizontal space as they can.

Anyways you might fine more detailed answers in http://doctype.com (like SO but design oriented).

Regards!

Edit: There's an interesting discussion about this topic [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1441410&page=6)

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).